# Does slice() alter the content of the vector in some circumstances?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, vector

In AS3, we've got a series of vectors containing ints. We want to chop off those vectors so we use slice as follows:

```
vector1 = vector1.slice( 0, a );
vector2 = vector2.slice( 0, b );
vector3 = vector3.slice( 0, c );
vector4 = vector4.slice( 0, d );
vector5 = vector5.slice( 0, e );
```

We found that in unpredictable but fairly consistent circumstances, one of these vectors would suddenly alter its content after the slice. The content seemed totally random and unrelated to any of the vectors.

Example: 1, 2, 3, 4 would become 16, 34, 244, 345 -- looked like random memory perhaps.

We were able to solve the problem by assigning to a separate vector first rather than having the return vector be the same as the vector on which we are operating. According to the docs it should not alter the content but simply return a new, smaller vector.

Am I missing something here or is this a known issue?

Comment: Never seen anything like that, since you say `unpredictable`, assuming you do not have a test case that used for testing. Which runtime version and platforms are you seeing this on?

Comment: It's certainly not supposed to. Of course `splice` does, but the behavior you describe is something I've never seen.

Comment: We're running it on a Mac, compiled using AIR SDK 17.0.0.172. We tried to reproduce the effect in a smaller sample but didn't get the same results which makes us think it's memory related. It only seems to be seen consistently in the spot described above in our fairly large project.

Comment: I would contact Adobe. Also, just a suggestion, since all your `slice` calls start at `0` and re-assign the original vector, you could just set the `length` instead: `vector1.length = a`, etc.

Comment: @screenglow, also did you try the newest AIR SDK? Certain issues get fixed all the time (but not announced as major update features). Worth a try...